# NetworkStream Equivelant

Tags: c#, .net, sockets, windows-runtime

I have been trying to create a metro application but there is a problem: StreamSocket doesn't really do what I want to do (I think)

Here is an excerpt my code from .Net that works:

```
        try
        {
            TCP = new TcpClient(server, port);
            Stream = TCP.GetStream();
            Read = new StreamReader(Stream);
            Write = new StreamWriter(Stream);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error connecting to " + server + ": " + e);
            return;
        }

        // Identify
        Write.WriteLine("LOGIN " + Username);
        Write.Flush();

        while (Connected)
        {
            try
            {
                if ((line = Read.ReadLine()) != null && Connected)
```

I can't get StreamSocket to work... it requires you to know the length of the string that's coming in and I don't know what it will be - it varies. Is there any way to do this that will work?

This is what I have but it doesn't work:

```
        try
        {
            // Connect to the server (in our case the listener we created in previous step).
            await Socket.ConnectAsync(new HostName("example.com"), "1111");
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            // If this is an unknown status it means that the error is fatal and retry will likely fail.
            if (SocketError.GetStatus(exception.HResult) == SocketErrorStatus.Unknown)
            {
                throw;
            }
        }

        // Create a DataWriter if we did not create one yet. Otherwise use one that is already cached.
        Writer = new DataWriter(Socket.OutputStream);
        Listener = new DataReader(Socket.InputStream);

        Debug.WriteLine(Socket.Information.RemoteAddress.CanonicalName); //Check if IP is correct

        SendRaw("LOGIN " + Nickname);

        string line = "";
        Connected = true;
        while (Connected)
        {
            if (Listener.UnconsumedBufferLength != 0)
            {
                line = Listener.ReadString(Listener.UnconsumedBufferLength);
                Debug.WriteLine(line);
            }
        }
    }

    async public void SendRaw(string str)
    {
        Writer.WriteString(str);

        // Write the locally buffered data to the network.
        try
        {
            await Writer.StoreAsync();
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            // If this is an unknown status it means that the error if fatal and retry will likely fail.
            if (SocketError.GetStatus(exception.HResult) == SocketErrorStatus.Unknown)
            {
                throw;
            }
        }
    }
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: What is your testing environment? The [MSDN reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.streams.datareader.unconsumedbufferlength(v=VS.85).aspx#Y200) states that you need Windows 8 Release Preview at least.

Comment: I am using Windows 8 RP. The problem is I dont get any input with the Metro application while the .Net application works fine

Comment: Can you see what is the value of `Listener.UnconsumedBufferLength` ?

Comment: It is always 0, the code is never executed.

Comment: Did you try with something like `line = Listener.ReadString(200);` to have a better idea about where is the problem?

Comment: The app exceptions like this:

`WinRT information: The operation attempted to access data outside the valid range

A first chance exception of type 'System.Exception' occurred in Foo.exe`

Comment: That means that you have less than 200 bytes to read... I would say that the problem comes from the sending part : can you try to call directly `DataWriter.WriteString` instead of the `SendRaw` method?

Comment: Do you have any control on the server side? Are you sure you send something?

Comment: Yep, I installed Wireshark and it sends the request, and I get a proper response from the server. It seems that the listener doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First things first: your original code is a DOS attack waiting to happen. If possible, I would recommend changing the protocol to include a length prefix before every string so you can tell how big it will be before allocating memory for it.

Second things second: the `DataReader` class must read a number of bytes into its internal buffer before it can interpret them. You read into this buffer by calling `LoadAsync`.

However, if you want to read a string of arbitrary length, you'll have to read into a buffer and scan for your newline yourself, resizing the buffer (or adding new buffers) as necessary if the newline isn't found, up to some maximum size.

**Update:**

Set `InputStreamOptions` to `Partial`; the you can call `LoadAsync` with an arbitrary large buffer size (e.g. 1024). After getting data, call `ReadString(UnconsumedBufferLength)`. Each time you do this, you may get part of a  line, a line, or more than a line. So you'll have to build up a `string` and then `Split` by `\n`, keeping any partial line at the end for the next time through the loop.

Comment: I didn't design the protocol, it's kind of like IRC

Comment: Ok, so I need to LoadAsync. The problem is that I don't know how big the packets are going to be - they vary from 3 to sizeof(string)... Is there any way to load any size buffer? By doing 119 (the first packet) I was able to get the response of the first packet...

Comment: @DavidDiaz You can still use a maximum line length to avoid the DoS issue. I believe IRC has a maximum of 512 bytes.

Comment: Thanks for that! It's not as nice as NetworkStream, but it works fine!